# Selection Sort in Java

Tags: java, sorting, selection

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class SortPractice {

private int[] railgun = {2,7,4,2,4,7,1};


public SortPractice() {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(railgun));
    SelectionSort(railgun);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(railgun));
}


public static void SelectionSort(int[] ray){

    for(int j = 0; j < ray.length; j++){

    int low = 0;
    for(int i = j; i < ray.length;i++){
        if(ray[i] < ray[low])
            low = i;
    }
    System.out.println(ray[low]);
    int temp = ray[low];
    ray[low] = ray[j];
    ray[j] = temp;
}

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   SortPractice steve = new SortPractice();
}
}
```

I have wrote this code out on paper and ran it through multiple times but for some reason its not working. i'm not sure if i'm missing a -1 or something and just didnt notice. Someone please take a look.

Im not looking for working code. just and explanation/fix to mine so i can better understand what i did wrong and how to fix it on my own. Thanks :)

Comment: Use a debugger or continue testing with the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe problem here: int low = 0;
try to change low = j

I tried, it worked

```
public static void SelectionSort(int[] ray){

    for(int j = 0; j < ray.length; j++){

    int low = j;
    for(int i = j; i < ray.length;i++){
        if(ray[i] < ray[low])
            low = i;
    }
    System.out.println(ray[low]);
    int temp = ray[low];
    ray[low] = ray[j];
    ray[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just worked it out and see why now! it was always editing the first number! silly mistake.

Comment: low is zero -> if(ray[i] < ray[low]) never true from second loop of j.
because at this time ray[0] is a minimum value of ray

Comment: Yeah! i see that now! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Its simple.

```
public static void SelectionSort(int[] numbers) {

    int tempVar = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < numbers.length - i; j++) {
            if (numbers[j - 1] > numbers[j]) {
                tempVar = numbers[j - 1];
                numbers[j - 1] = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = tempVar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the link to understand it [Bubble sort](https://www.udemy.com/blog/bubble-sort-java/)

Answer (score 0):

int low = j;

otherwise you're always comparing numbers to the very first one.

Note:

1. Your naming is terrible: wtf is railgun? wtf is ray?
2. Methods should start with lowercased letters -> Selection should be selection
3. Indentation!

Don't say you're just a beginner. These are issues everybody should first learn.